# Regular expression: Delete everything between X and Y in filename

Tags: regex

I have a lot of files with the beginning xxx-yy. Both xxx and yy may vary. Example:

356-01 Nielsen - Sovnen, Op. 18.mp3

Everything between "356-01" and ".mp3" must be deleted so the new filename is:

356-01.mp3

".mp3" also varies. The expression should cover ".flac" also.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: `^(\d{3}-\d{2}).*(\..+)$`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming xxx and yy are digits, you can do

```
s/(\d\d\d-\d\d).*(\..+$)/\1\2/
```

The `\.` at the end is a literal period and `.+$` means every character up to the end, so it should get the extension because the `.*` before it is greedy.

The find and replace were written between the slashes and use capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

My question was based on that I thought to have made ​​some in advance. It now turns out that it does not work and therefore I have to reformulate the task. I'm sorry.

I have a lot of files beginning with 01, 02, 03 and so on. It wil never exeece 99. Example:

01 Nielsen - Sovnen, Op. 18.mp3

A 3-digit number* must be added to the beginning of the new filename and everything between "01" and ".mp3" must be deleted so the new filename is:

356-01.mp3

".mp3" also varies. The expression should cover ".flac" also.

*) What 3-digit number you use in your response is not important as the command will be added as a line in a larger bash script that I edit manually before each use